# Must a community wiki post follow the pattern of a Q&A?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I'm just curious whether it is acceptable to post questions and answers that are usually considered off-topic. I don't know how to explain it better so I'll give an example to illustrate the idea:

#### Example: Webpages for programming newbies

Suppose I've done a massive amount research, surfing and browsing to find webpages where you can practice coding/programming, like [spoj.com](http://spoj.com), [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) and so on.

Would it be considered off-topic if I post a question "Where can I learn to code?" on SE (probably on StackOverflow or Programmers) and answered to this question with the list I prepared as a community wiki?

---

This is just an example. I would like to learn whether community posts should follow the Q&A pattern or we can treat them as a real wiki, where you can add sources and share your knowledge with the community.

I perceive community wiki posts as something slightly different than ordinary posts. I've already read the definition here ([What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)) but I still have got many doubts.

I'd be really grateful if someone could resolve my doubts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Must a community wiki post follow the pattern of a Q&A?

Yes.

> I'm just curious whether it is acceptable to post questions and answers that are usually considered off-topic.

No, it is not acceptable.

> Would it be considered off-topic if I post a question "Where can I learn to code?" on SE (probably on StackOverflow or Programmers) and answered to this question with the list I prepared as a community wiki?

Yes, that is completely off topic.

> This is just an example. I would like to learn whether community posts should follow the Q&A pattern or we can treat them as a real wiki

You *can* treat them as a wiki, insofar as anyone is able to edit them to improve the quality of the content in the post at any time. **The post being a wiki, and being the collaborative work of many people, in no way lowers the quality standards expected of questions or answers, changes their scope, or what's allowable.** It's simply a way for multiple people to come together to create a question and/or answer that is better than could have been done by someone alone.

> I perceive community wiki posts as something slightly different than ordinary posts.

They are *slightly* different.  But they're different in how one goes about creating the content, they are not *any* different in terms of what type of content is or is not acceptable.  If a particular question or answer wouldn't be acceptable as a non-wiki post, it's equally unacceptable as a wiki post.